# write python list of tuples to sqlite

Tags: python

How to write list of tuples to sqlite db?
For e.g. `mylist = [(1,2), (3,1), (1,4)]`

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("INSERT INTO table_name VALUES mylist")
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html In the first section you already have your answer. Always check the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
c.execute('INSERT INTO  table_name(first_column_name, second_column_name) VALUES(?, ?)',var)
```